# Android Java Pjsip - one way audio after reinvite

Tags: java, android, openssl, pjsip, opus

We are having a problem when we are trying to reinvite a call.

**Case 1 - working:** When A calls B, and B answers the call and then A puts on hold - on the B side pjsip music is played and after A un hold the call the audio is transmitted in both ways - call works normally.

**Case 2 - NOT working:** A calls B, and B answers the call, and then if B puts call on hold, on A side there is no pjsip music played to inform user that the call is on hold. Also, when B decides to un hold the call there is one way audio transmitted from A -> B like ptt (A can't hear B).
After putting on hold we got several same errors like below, unlike after un hold when we are constantly getting errors for every transmitted package like: `srtp0x55a4c04d70  Failed to unprotect SRTP, pkt size=49, err=authentication failure`

So, I have checked the logs and if B after answer immediately puts call on hold and then un hold it - he is sending the packages, but the A side doesn't receive it. (Logs on call end)

We are using pjsip 2.10. (latest), opus 1.3.1 (latest), openSSL 1.1.1g, also TLS over UDP. We tried building pjsip lib without opus, and some pjsip builds we found on the internet but same problem occurred. We cannot disable TLS because it is mandatory for connection to the server (Asterisk 13.14.0).
Calls are established on GSM @8kHz. If we enable opus for some users on server and establish call on opus codec, we experienced the same PTT (one-way audio) behavior.
Implementation is in Flutter mobile application, but pjsip part is done on native Java side.
PjsipPlugin.java

```
public void holdCall() {
    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);
    mFirstCall.setHold(prm);
}

 public void unHoldCall() {
    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);
    prm.getOpt().setFlag(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD);
    prm.getOpt().setAudioCount(1);
    mFirstCall.reinvite(prm);
}
```

MyCall.java

```
@Override
public void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam prm)
  {
    CallInfo callInfo;
    try
    {
      callInfo = getInfo();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      Log.e(TAG,"Exception occurred in onCallMediaState: getInfo: " + e.getMessage());
      return;
}

CallMediaInfoVector mediaInfoVector = callInfo.getMedia();

for (int i = 0; i < mediaInfoVector.size(); i++)
{
  CallMediaInfo mediaInfo = mediaInfoVector.get(i);
  int type = mediaInfo.getType();
  int status = mediaInfo.getStatus();

  if (type == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
          && (status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE
          || status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD))
  {
    try
    {
      Media media = getAudioMedia(i);//getMedia(i);
      AudioMedia am = AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(media);

      PjSipManager.mEndPoint.audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia().startTransmit(am);
      am.startTransmit(PjSipManager.mEndPoint.audDevManager().getPlaybackDevMedia());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
     // e.printStackTrace();
      Log.e(TAG,"Exception occurred in onCallMediaState: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}

PjSipManager.observer.notifyCallMediaState(this);}
```

Comment: The error "Failed to unprotect SRTP.." indicates there was SRTP issue (not necessarily the main cause though), perhaps you could try to apply the patch from https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/pull/2531

Answer (score 1):

I'm just at the same situation, using the same environment as described in your case.

Actually this is not an answer but maybe can help you to check behavior on your side, because I think that code is valid, but there is some specific configuration which should be set, and not realy good described on pjsip page (from my point of view).

I've tried many different combinations of the configuration and found the reason (in my case), but stil didn't figure out how to resolve the issue.
Can you maybe try this combination on your system and confirm the behavior.
The problematic point is that when both client use the configuration for the SRTP.
So let's go directly to the code:

client A and client B has the usage of the srtp set to mandatory/optional

```
mAccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpUse(pjmedia_srtp_use.PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY);
mAccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpSecureSignaling(0);
```

in this case you'll get the expected behavior, you can make call from A to B, B can answer, set on hold on B side -> and will get a lot of "**Failed to unprotect SRTP**" messages, and wen you unhold from B the caller A can't hear anything because of failed decryption on A side. --> So this is actually the problem here.

Ok, tried little bit different combination in the code, using SRTP on client A, and DISABLED SRTP flag on the B client --> works

Client A:

```
mAccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpUse(pjmedia_srtp_use.**PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY**);
mAccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpSecureSignaling(0);
```

Client B:

```
mAccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpUse(pjmedia_srtp_use.**PJMEDIA_SRTP_DISABLED**);
mAccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpSecureSignaling(0);
```

So, I'm still struggling to find the best combination of the parameters for the pjsip to use the same configuration on both side..

Also, when I try to use configuration for both clients to use DISABLED srtp config, then I can see in the logs of pjsip library that invite is received, but it's not propagated to the java handler so I could't catch that event (strange behavior) to get the early/calling event state,..
I don't want to use the clients with disabled srtp, but this is also combination what I've tried and it's little bit strange.

I will try some other combinations, and do some updates if I find some other useful infos..

Comment: Thanks for the shared info. I tried also that combination and I can say that I got same behavior as you do, strange... will definitely investigate further in that direction. If you found and additional info or working scenario, please share :)